# Using Node/Express, How Do I Check If Specifically and Only index.html is requested?

Tags: node.js, express

Since using app.use and app.use('/') means that it will apply for every request, I want to check for only requests to index.html. How would I do that for node/express?

Example:

app.use('/')

Callback handler only works for request made to '/' and not '/styles'

Answer (score 0):

Use app.get('/'). The difference is using .use and .get

.use will match everything after '/'
.get looks for specifically '/'